# Linker Command Failed with exit code 1: duplicate symbol - no .m file

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, opengl-es

I've seen this issue in other posts but in my case I am using a sphere.h file that contains the data of vertices of a sphere, that is, a 3D model for my game project. I import my sphere.h file into my objective-C Class as follows:

```
 #import "SceneEnergyGlobe.h"
 #import "sphere.h"

 @interface SceneEnergyGlobe() {

 }
 @property (strong, nonatomic) GLKTextureInfo *textureInfo0;

 @end

 .....
```

When I compile my project, I receive this compile error. How I can fix this?

Here is the contents of sphere.h:

```
 #ifndef SPHERE_HEADER
 #define SPHERE_HEADER

 unsigned int sphereNumVerts = 2280;

 float sphereVerts [] = {

   0.0743889747124915, -0.49384436095363, -0.0241703260695731,
   0.190555012144643, -0.979722062440628, -0.0619150039460291,
   0.000000, 0.95,
   0.0632787269334132, -0.49384436095363, -0.0459747512867777,
   0.162096012330563, -0.979722074526971, -0.11776900895863,
   0.050000, 0.95,
   0.125000004921036, -0.475528075643002, -0.0908176095396332,
   0.269869905435848, -0.942722669663907, -0.196071931295133,
   .....
```

Comment: Did you declare any variable with global scope, so external of @interface/@end blocks? Show more code.

Comment: This is not enough to help you. But one other thing, className should be Capital as "Sphere".

Comment: What happens if you call `#include "sphere.h`?

Comment: I included part of the contents of sphere.h. it is not an Objective-C class

Comment: The problem happens when I have another Objective-C class and I also import sphere.h file

Comment: The linker error message should tell you which of the symbols is duplicated. I bet it is `sphereNumVerts` and `sphereVerts`. Which means we are down to regular C issues here. I think you should declare them as `external` in the header file and implement them without `external` key word in one of the .m files. (still ex @implementation and its @end). But I am not 100% positive about that.  Plain C is decades ago for me. :-)  Well, give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

For every implementation file (`.m`) that includes `sphere.h` a new copy of the vertices array will be created.  When these implementation files are linked together you get your duplicate symbol error.

The best approach is to change this in `sphere.h`:

```
#define sphereNumVerts 2280
extern float sphereVerts[sphereNumVerts];
```

And add an implementation file (`sphere.m`) that contains the definition of `sphereVerts`:

```
#import "sphere.h"

float sphereVerts[sphereNumVerts] = {
    0.0743889747124915, -0.49384436095363, -0.0241703260695731,
    ...
};
```

BTW, those look like big numbers for `float`; are you sure you don't want `double`?

(EDIT: My previous suggestion was wrong; you'll get duplicate symbols using `const` in a header file too.  I have changed this to a `#define`).

Answer (score -1):

It is a very very very bad idea to create and initialize variables in .h files!!!